# Как присвоить класс при нажатии на внутренний блок?

Tags: javascript, css

Есть несколько таких блоков кода, как при нажатии на кнопку отправить присвоить классу mainli ещё один класс active?

```
<li class="mainli">
        <div class="product-h">
            <img width="300" height="300" src="img.jpg" />
            <div class="product-meta">
                <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">Text</h2>
                <div class="case">
                    <h6>Title6</h6>

                    <ul class="vkus">
                        <li class="qwe">...</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="line">...</div>
                </div>

                <div class="case">
                    <h6>...</h6>

                    <p><span class="ryer">...</span></p>
                    <div class="line"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="case">
                    <h6>...</h6>
                    <div сlass="smes">
                    </div>
                    <ul class="sostav">

                        <li сlass="case">
                            <div class="aqwe"><i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;txt</div>
                            <div class="aqwe"></div>
                        </li>

                        <li сlass="case-robusta">
                            <div class="robusta-n robusta-r_70"><i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;txt</div>
                            <div class="robusta-t">txt</div>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                    <div class="line"></div>

                </div>
                <span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">390&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol"></span></span>
                </span>
            </div>
    </a><a class="button product_type_external buys" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="color: white;">Отправить</a></div>
</li>
```

Мой код присваивает всем mainli класс актив можно как-то это исправить?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".buys").click(function() {
    $(".mainli").removeClass("active");
    $(".mainli").addClass("active");
    return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в зависимости текущего элемента `$(this)` и на его ближайшего подходящего родителя .closest(".mainli")

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".buys").click(function() {
    $(".mainli").removeClass("active");
    $(this).closest(".mainli").addClass("active"); // По правке Igor
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mainli.active {
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="mainli">
        <div class="product-h">
            <img width="300" height="300" src="img.jpg" />
            <div class="product-meta">
                <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">Text</h2>
                <div class="case">
                    <h6>Title6</h6>

                    <ul class="vkus">
                        <li class="qwe">...</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="line">...</div>
                </div>

                <div class="case">
                    <h6>...</h6>

                    <p><span class="ryer">...</span></p>
                    <div class="line"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="case">
                    <h6>...</h6>
                    <div сlass="smes">
                    </div>
                    <ul class="sostav">

                        <li сlass="case">
                            <div class="aqwe"><i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;txt</div>
                            <div class="aqwe"></div>
                        </li>

                        <li сlass="case-robusta">
                            <div class="robusta-n robusta-r_70"><i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;txt</div>
                            <div class="robusta-t">txt</div>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                    <div class="line"></div>

                </div>
                <span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">390&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol"></span></span>
                </span>
            </div>
    </a><a class="button product_type_external buys" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="color: white;">Отправить</a></div>
</li>
```

Comment: `$(this).closest(".mainli").addClass("active");`

Comment: более хороший вариант, поправила в соответствии с ним

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".buys").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // убираем класс active
        $(".mainli.active").removeClass("active");
        // добавляем класс active для блока внутри которого находится нажимаемый buys
        $(this).closest(".mainli").addClass("active");  
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Не срабатывает почему-то

Comment: проверил,  срабатывает
https://jsfiddle.net/x404/a8xwd43u/1/